# Mobile Google Analytics Virtual Screen Views

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, web-analytics, universal-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I've searched around and can only find some very vague documentation on my question.

What I am wondering is:

Say you have a Mobile app that you are wanting to use mobile Google analytics to track users. Say its a e-commerce site and therefore you have a product screen named "products".

This is not ideal for someone that wants to find the top products on their mobile app...as the screen name is simply "Products".

Ideally you would want the actual product name in the screen views section of Google Analytics. The problem with this though is that it will look ugly across the top of the actual screen. Currently it says "products" across the top of the screen.

Now for the question:

Is there a way to pass the actual product name as the screen name but still present "Product" at the top of the screen when a user is viewing the app?

If so..I would love to know how so I can relay to my developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that google analytics cover this in their documentation on page view:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {
  'page': '/my-overridden-page?id=1',
  'title': 'my overridden page'       <---
});
```

Please let me know if you meant for something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the screen name as described [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/screens). Specifically:

```
    // Set screen name.
    // Where path is a String representing the screen name.
    t.setScreenName(path);
```

you can pass anything in the path variable and it can even be your product's name.